# Error in android studio : Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.2

Tags: java, android

I am new to coding android I install android studio 3.1.4, but it is not working, and it has several errors.

Errors:

[image]

and my main java class is like this :

[image]

How can I fix it ??

it's my build.gradle :

[image]

Comment: clean and rebuilt project

Comment: add gradle dependency for more clear

Answer (score 0):

build.gradle file have some errors:

1. implementation appcompat and its below line are
   commented.(Uncomment these two lines)
2. all library version shoule be same,such as 27.0.2
3. compileSdkVersion and targetSdkVersion are also should be set to 27